# Passing a model from a view (through ActionLink ) to an action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am learning .net MVC by working on a mini project in which I am calling a view which shows details of a model passed to it. Now I also have some buttons ( to edit , delete etc) that model . I wanted to know if I can pass the model directly to an action in its controller through ActionLink  so that the action can call another view to edit the details of that model.
Here is the view I am working with::

```
@model MvcBooksList.Models.Book
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Book Details";
}


@if (Model != null)
{
    <div>
        <div>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BookName)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BookName)
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Author)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Author)
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Publisher)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Publisher)
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pages)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Pages)
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Category)
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Subcategory)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Subcategory)
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AddedBy)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AddedBy)
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModifiedBy)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ModifiedBy)
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AddedOn)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AddedOn)
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastModifiedOn)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastModifiedOn)
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", }) |      // CAN I PASS MODEL HERE WHICH IS PASSED
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", }) |    //TO THIS VIEW
            @Html.ActionLink("Delist", "Delist",  }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Cancel") 
        </div>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <h3>No Book with that Name</h3>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass complete model to the edit or delete view , it's an overkill. Just pass id of the book to those views by sending route values in action link.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit",new{id=bookid})
```

Here bookid is the id of the book. Please remember to use id as a parameter in your Edit action method.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion . One thing though , I am not using Id in my model. I am using a database with BookName as Primary key. Will it work if I pass bookname as mentioned above.??

Comment: Yes it will work but you need to modify the code to use new{name=Model.Bookname}
and make the same change in action method as well.